# Overwrite empty string in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, string, object

I need that child class StringBuilder would pass the string to the parent class and call the minus method. The following code does not work unless I won't hardcode the string in the constructor. With numbers this works just fine. Why doesn't it overwrite the string? Or maybe I'm doing everything completely wrong?

```
class Builder {
    constructor() {
        this.int = 0
        this.str = ''
    }

    minus(...n) {
        this.int = n.reduce((sum, current) => sum - current, this.int)
        this.str = this.str.slice(0, -n)
        return this
    }
}

class IntBuilder extends Builder {
    constructor(int) {
        super(int)
    }
}

class StringBuilder extends Builder {
    constructor(str) {
        super(str)
    }
}

let number = new IntBuilder()
number.minus(100, 99)

console.log(number)

let string = new StringBuilder('Hello')

string.minus(2)

console.log(string)
```

Comment: Your `Builder` constructor does not take any parameters. Declare a parameter and assign that parameter to `this.str`.

Comment: @Mushroomator By the assignment, if no string is passed, it should take empty string by default. Moreover, this.str.slice throws an error of undefined

Comment: This looks like a bad inheritance scheme. A `StringBuilder` should not have a `.int` property, and an `IntBuilder` should not have a  `.str` property.

Comment: @Bergi, well, I agree with you. But it must be one class for actions with both integers and strings. I don't know how to make common methods for both classes so that integers wont inherit strings and vice versa

Comment: "*it must be one class for actions for both integers and strings*" - no it doesn't? Both builders may share an interface, i.e. both implement a `minus` method, but that doesn't mean both have to inherit from the same class.

Comment: This is the assignment: 
"Create a base class that will contain common methods. Then create 2 child classes (inherit from base): IntBuilder in ES6 style and StringBuilder in ES5 style. " 
I know, that my stringbuilder is not in ES5 style, don't mind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Builder constructor does not take any parameters. Declare a parameter and assign that parameter to `this.str`. You can use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) to ensure it will be initialized to whatever you want even when the constructor is called without parameters.

```js
class Builder {
  constructor(str = "") {
    this.int = 0
    this.str = str
  }

  minus(...n) {
    this.int = n.reduce((sum, current) => sum - current, this.int)
    this.str = this.str.slice(0, -n);
    return this;
  }
}

class IntBuilder extends Builder {
  constructor(int) {
    super(int)
  }
}

class StringBuilder extends Builder {
  constructor(str) {
    super(str)
  }
}

let number = new IntBuilder()
number.minus(100, 99)

console.log(number)

let string = new StringBuilder('Hello')

string.minus(2)

console.log(string)
```

Comment: OMG, I thought I can't assign default values in brackets :D Thank you!